# Google Drive resumable upload in v3

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I am looking for some help/example to perform a resumeable upload to Google Drive using the new v3 REST API in Java.

I know there is a low level description here: [Upload files | Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumabl). But at the moment I am not willing to understand any of these low level requests, if there isn't another, simpler method ( like former MediaHttpUploader, which is deprecated now...)

What I currently do is:

```
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName(name);
    fileMetadata.setDescription(...);
    fileMetadata.setParents(parents);
    fileMetadata.setProperties(...);
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(..., file);
    drive.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent).execute();
```

But for large files, this isn't good if the connection interrupts.

Comment: You are using simple upload which can perform well if you have stable connection and small file size, I would change requests to html type and use resumable upload option which has example on api page.

Comment: https://github.com/PiyushXCoder/google-drive-ResumableUpload/blob/master/ResumableUpload.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just created an implementation on that recently. It will create a new file on your DriveFolder and return its metadata when the task succeeds. While uploading, it will also update the listener with uploading info. I added comments to make it auto explanable:

```
public Task<File> createFile(java.io.File yourfile, MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener uploadListener) {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {
            //Generates an input stream with your file content to be uploaded
            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("yourFileMimeType", yourfile);
            //Creates an empty Drive file           
            File metadata = new File() 
                    .setParents(parents) 
                    .setMimeType(yourFileMimeType)
                    .setName(yourFileName);

            //Builds up the upload request
            Drive.Files.Create uploadFile = mDriveService.files().create(metadata, mediaContent);
            //This will handle the resumable upload
            MediaHttpUploader uploader = uploadBackup.getMediaHttpUploader();
            //choose your chunk size and it will automatically divide parts
            uploader.setChunkSize(MediaHttpUploader.MINIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE); 
            //according to Google, this enables gzip in future (optional)
            uploader.setDisableGZipContent(false);  versions
            //important, this enables resumable upload
            uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false); 
            //listener to be updated
            uploader.setProgressListener(uploadListener);

            return uploadFile.execute();
        });
    }
```

And make your `Activity` extends `MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener` so you have real time updates on the file progress:

```
@Override
public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) {
    String sizeTemp = "Uploading"
            + ": "
            + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, uploader.getNumBytesUploaded())
            + "/"
            + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, totalFileSize);
    runOnUiThread(() -> textView.setText(sizeTemp));
}
```

For calculating the progress percentage, you simply do:

```
double percentage = uploader.getNumBytesUploaded() / totalFileSize
```

Or use this one:

```
uploader.getProgress()
```

It gives you the percentage of bytes that have been uploaded, represented between 0.0 (0%) and 1.0 (100%). But be sure to have your content length specified, otherwise it will throw `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As it is stated here, MediaHTTPUploader is deprecated: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/master/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/media/MediaHttpUploader.java :(

Comment: @Viatorus `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` doesn't mean MediaHTTPUploader is deprecated. It may be used to supress deprecation in whatever deprecated method or class being used inside that class, as there's no `@Deprecation` annotation at all. =)

Comment: thanks, after All day long, I found it, and use with Api 29

Comment: Using :  new MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener() {
Override
public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
final String sizeTemp = "Uploading"
+ ": "
+ Formatter.formatShortFileSize(mContext, uploader.getNumBytesUploaded());
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
mProgress.setMessage(sizeTemp);
}
});

Comment: @NoorHossain glad my answer helped you! About the code in the answer, we don't need to make use of `new` because the `Activity` is already extending from `MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener`, so you just need to implement its `progressChanged` method. Also, for `runOnUiThread`, I've used the `lambda` notation  (Java 8) to make it cleaner.

Comment: @DimasMendes, thanks for your quick reply, can provide some code , how call implementing listener in your case in class ? clearly I want to know how to call public Task<File> createFile(java.io.File yourfile, MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener uploadListener) , how I pass the uploadlistener in this method which implemented in class level ?

Comment: @NoorHossain if you create a question I can answer that in a better way. You can basically create an `interface` signature or an `abstract class` (which is better for this case) with the methods above. On another class, you inherit from the recently created one using `extends`.